Two select statements in one Query
I'm new to SQL and I'm having trouble with a pretty basic problem. I have a with column: "primaryProfession" in this column there are actors and actresses. I want to return a result that shows how many Actors there are total and how many Actresses with one query.
This is my code:
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(primaryProfession), 
        FROM title      
        WHERE primaryProfession = "Actor" ) AS "Actors",
        (SELECT COUNT(primaryProfession), 
        FROM title
        WHERE primaryProfession = "Actress") AS "Actresses" 
FROM title;

I want it to produce two columns: "Actors" and "Actresses" and show me the total number of each.

You had tagged two different database products. Please tag only one; I have removed both tags. Please tag the actual DBMS you're using.

You also accepted a product specific answer. Be kind to other readers looking for a solution, add a tag for the dbms you're using.

You may use conditional aggregation here:
SELECT
    SUM(primaryProfession = 'Actor') AS Actors,
    SUM(primaryProfession = 'Actress') AS Actresses
FROM title;

This approach is succinct and also only requires SQLite to make a single pass over the title table.

Well, in case you want to get data only where the primaryProfession is either Actor or Actress, you should add a WHERE clause to improve the performance!
